# anime slashes and hard impact effects in blender 2.9 eevee

Tags: mesh, texturing, particles, eevee-render-engine

In blender 2.91 I'm using the eevee render engine. I want to know if it's possible to make anime style slashes, not sword trails, and impact like effects.

What I mean by slash, is when they typically do a major cut or kill their target. Whether this be through the particle system, texture, or a mesh. What I have tried doesn't look to good so can someone tell me a better way of making them?

[image]

my impact
[image]

my slash
[image]

if anyone needs them

https://pasteall.org/blend/12a3558b5f15429db885133cc5adbdc4

https://pasteall.org/blend/970b6fb2901a487aae3b3633236f0817

Comment: Can you show what you have done and how? Would be nice to see it.

Comment: Just added them.

Comment: Actually it looks really good, this, combined with good shader will do the job

Comment: Really, I thought it wasn't good. I'm still a beginner and don't know much about blender yet.

Comment: Yeah, dont worry. (almost) Everything is achievable. Would you please share your file? Ive made a shader, but i want to see if it will look good on your object(im using the cube now)

Comment: Just added them.

Comment: Alright, ive made [something](https://imgur.com/a/GEDXfEx), tell me if thats what you are looking for.

Comment: I was trying to give is a little bit of a curve, like it was a little more spherical, but yea something like that. How did you do that.

Comment: I did it with a shader, i will show you in an answer

Comment: Just posted it, im not sure how the "Slash" thing looks like, so i havent spoke about it

Answer (score 1):

About the impact, using your already made object, I gave it the needed shader and got result.

[image]

It's described like this:

First, we get the Object Coordinates, sop we get the "-1 to 1" gradient. Then, using Separate XYZ we get the Z channel of the vector. Now, our Output is BW, going from -1 through 0 and then 1.  After this, we use a math node, performing action Absolute- this will ignore the sign before each number, so all negative values will become positive, while keeping the positive as is. Right now, we don't have a "-1 through 0 to 1" gradient, we have "1 to 0 to 1"- this will result a black line in the middle.

After this, we use Mix RGB nodes, set to "Color Burn" and "Color Dodge" to control the line. Mora Fac on the Color Burn will result a thicker line, and more Fac on the Color Dodge will result a harder falloff(harder edge between black and white).

Now, we use this thing as a mask for our Mix Shader. By putting Emission in the first socket, it will appear where the value is zero. The Transparent BSDF will appear on white values- this way the black line from our mask is now emission, and the rest is transparent. By adjusting the falloff between black and white, we can make the emission to blend with the transparency and so it will be faded on the edges.

So now you have it. But the problem is- how to move it?
That's fairly simple- we cant do it from the BW part, but because its all formed at the midpoint of the Object coordinates, we can move that mid point and thus move the line. So, we just add a Vector Math node before the BW part and we add some value on the axis we are using- in our case Z. Then, you can keyframe the Z axis value and boom, you have and animation,

Comment: Thanks, it looks really good. When I finally start animating ill see how it really looks but its still better than what I started with. For the slash it was mainly for dramatic slices like when a character rushes another character. I made it that way, so I can put one end on the tip of the sword and the other one on the target. I could also use this trick on it, to give it extra flare.